# Extract table information currently in Word

Tags: database, ms-word, text-extraction

I have 2000 individual Word documents each with a table that includes data (legal document).  How can I efficiently move those tables from Word into a new searchable database without having to copy and paste each one?

Nothing beyond copy and paste into Excel and then create a database.  Will take too many hours.